# sum two row with condition

Tags: sql

I have one table as below if two rows has same item and location then two one should become one one row and give the total of qty

```
item location qty
a      1010    10
a      1020     5
a      1010     5
b      1010     2
b      1010     5
b      1020     1
c      1010     5
```

result

```
item location qty
a     1010    15
a     1020     5
b     1010     7
b     1020     1
c     1010     5
```

Comment: look towards using `group by` and `sum`

Comment: don't work. if group by item, it will lost the qty with diferent location

Comment: you know you can `group by item, location` and `Select item, location, sum(qty) as qty` right?  Group by should typically contain all values not aggregated.

Comment: can you show the attempt?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: anyone know how to use openedge  procedure editor export the sql result to csv file with DELIMITER ","

Comment: @Joe Please avoid combining different questions under one thread. Post a separate question if its not already been asked in SO

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT item, location, SUM(qty)
FROM xTable
GROUP BY item, location
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.item, t.location, SUM(t.qty)
FROM test t
GROUP BY t.item, t.location
ORDER BY t.item, t.location
```